# java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to play.twirl.api.Html

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm taking a project and upgrading it to Play 2.5 (from 2.1). One problem I've hit is with this test:

```
  val actualResult : Result = ...

  val it = Iteratee.fold[Html, List[Html]](List.empty) {
      (a, b) => {
        b :: a
      }
    }

    val bodyIt = actualResult.body.asInstanceOf[Enumerator[Html]].apply(it)
    val bodyItResult = Await.result(bodyIt, 1 second)
    val bodyList = Await.result(bodyItResult.run, 1 second)
    val bodyText = bodyList.toString

    bodyText should include(callbackUrl)
  }
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to play.twirl.api.Html
```

Thrown in the iterator. Why can't it cast the object?

Comment: `[B` points that `actualResult.body` is an `Enumerator[Array[...]]` instead of an `Enumerator[Html]`

Comment: @Sergey It's `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]`, does this mean I need to manually squash the Array of Bytes into HTML?

Comment: I haven't used Play 2.1 and don't recall the details of forming result's bodies there, but perhaps [body parsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#body-parsers) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergey pointed out, this was a type mismatch, and I solved it as follows:

```
  val actualResult : Result = ...

  val it = Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], List[Array[Byte]]]](List.empty) {
      (a, b) => {
        b :: a
      }
    }

    val bodyIt = actualResult.body.asInstanceOf[Enumerator[Html]].apply(it)
    val bodyItResult = Await.result(bodyIt, 1 second)
    val bodyList = Await.result(bodyItResult.run, 1 second)
    val bodyBytes = bodyList.head
    val bodyText = new String(bodyBytes)
    bodyText should include(callbackUrl)
  }
```